# How can I simplify this code with a loop function

Tags: javascript, loops, google-sheets, copy, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet that changes cell A2, from 1 to 12, and then copies 3 separate ranges on the same sheet into 3 separate ranges in another sheet. so in total 36 copy and past values tasks. I have just recorded a Macro but it is very slow so can I use a loop function to speed it all up.

One additional point is that i store the original value of A2 in a cell then copy it back so the spreadsheet returns to its initial position at the end of the task.

As above

```
function GraphDataCopy() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('I8').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Rolling Forecast SUMMARY'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Graph Data Sheet'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('\'Rolling Forecast SUMMARY\'!A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Rolling Forecast SUMMARY'), true);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('1');
      spreadsheet.getRange('B13:D13').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Graph Data Sheet'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('B6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('\'Rolling Forecast SUMMARY\'!B13:D13').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

And so on to

```
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Rolling Forecast SUMMARY'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Graph Data Sheet\'!B2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Comment: Which specific application are we talking about here? Excel? Google Sheets?

Comment: Oh sorry, It's google sheets